# Reading given name of German great-grandaunt?

Tags: 19th-century, germany, birth-records, palaeography, naming

I cannot read this name, which is the name of one of the older sisters of my great-grandfather. It is supposed to be a german female name. This was written in 1878.

[image]

Sample of handwriting by the same guy:

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The name is **Agnes**.

You can compare each of the letters to those shown in this [BYU Script Tutorial](https://script.byu.edu/Pages/German/en/alphabet.aspx) for German handwriting.

I extracted the relevant letters from the alphabet image on that site, and put them together in one image. I've included your image below for easy comparison.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks ! Are you 100% sure, or do you need me to do what PolyGeo tells me to do (that is, giving other samples of the same handwriting) ?

Comment: @Bregalad I'm quite sure, but it never hurts to have a bit more context. Also, for anyone referencing this in the future I think it would be useful if you could add a century date tag to the question (I'm assuming it's 19th-century but will let you add it).

Comment: @vevet So, now that I did the update, can you confirm or deny that the name is indeed Agnes ?

Comment: @Bregalad Yes there's no doubt in my mind it says Agnes

Answer (score 6):

I also found it useful to have this PDF around for comparing the letters. The benefit being you can zoom it in quite a bit:
https://feefhs.org/sites/default/files/guide/german-gothic.pdf

Once you get an initial idea about what the letters are likely to be you can use the following tool to generate a sample which you can check against:
http://altdeutsche-schrift.de/adsschreiben.php#schriftfeld

[image: example handwriting]