# What does 1898 wedding/memorial announcement from Germany, Austria, or Slovenia say?

Tags: germany, palaeography, marriage-practices, austria

I have what I assume is a wedding announcement or memorial:
[image]

I believe this memorializes the marriage between Alois Kovach and Josephine Gregorčič who were married in either Germany, Austria, or Slovenia.  Does anyone know what language this is written in?  I see that in both German and Modern Slovene January is `Januar`, which may be what is written but the `n` and `u` would be very similar, so I'm unsure of my reading.

Is this a wedding announcement?  Does it give the date of marriage and location?  What other information does it tell us about the marriage?  What are the spellings of the names written?  What language is this written in?  Is there any known history to this heart shaped memorial?

Comment: I would say this is German because "geb" is a common abbreviation for German 'geboren' which means 'born'.  See https://familysearch.org/wiki/en/German_Word_List  In any case, German script tutorials might be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a wedding souvenir and it is in German

> Alois Kowatsch
>  Josefa Kowatsch
>  geb Gregortschitsch
>   Vermählt
>   10. Januar 1898
>  zu Oestereich.

that is:
[groom] Alois Kowatsch
[bride] Josefa Kowatsch, maiden name Gregortschitsch
married 10. January 1898 in Austria

The resources mentioned in [Reading given name of German great-grandaunt?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9934/reading-given-name-of-german-great-grandaunt) would have helped you with reading the typeface.